# Wait + refresh a page

Tags: python, selenium

In `Selenium`, is there an *idiomatic* way to refresh a page if a condition is `False` after a given timeout? For example,

```
  elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "some-class")))
```

If `elem1` is still not present after 60 seconds, how do I refresh a page and start waiting over again?

Answer (score 4):

Reload the site when `NoSuchElementException` occurs. I would suggest doing this in combination with `implicitly_wait`.

Also, using `find_element_by_class_name` would make the code less verbose and perhaps more readable as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()    
driver.implicitly_wait(60)

# try 2 times
for _ in range(1, 3):
    try:
        elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("some-class")
        break
    except NoSuchElementException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
else:
   # handle cases when element was not found
```

Comment: how will "driver.refresh()" make it do one more iteration "
    elem1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("some-class")" over again?

Comment: @Alan Coromano thanks, didn't catch that part of the question, updated

Answer (score 1):

If the WebDriverWait time is exceeded then it will throw a TimeoutException. Put the wait in a for loop with the try:...except: around it, add a delay in the except: clause. If no exception occurs then the page has loaded and you can break out of the for loop.